# PHP multi-line echo not putting variables within the correct divs?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, echo

I am working on a PHP loop for Wordpress and populating the content with variables.

Currently I have an echo to produce the HTML blocks for the loop that looks like this:

```
echo '<div class="col-sm-4 retailer" data-state="'.$state.'">
        <div class="locationName">'.the_title().'</div>
        <div class="locationAddress">'.the_field("address").'</div>
      </div>';
```

However, in the outputted HTML the 2 variables(the_title and the_field("address")) are being placed below the content block instead of within their respective divs like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 retailer" data-state="Alaska">
    <div class="locationName"></div>
    <div class="locationAddress"></div>
</div>Location #1 81234 Sample Dr.
```

Can anyone tell me why the variables aren't being contained to the correct divs? Thanks!

Comment: Functions the_title() and the_field() must return their values, but they are probably just echoing them out.

Comment: @ErkiA - yup, it's `get_the_title()` and `get_the_field()` for not echoing.

Comment: The custom field is from the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), so I used `get_field` for that and it worked perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: gr8, just a FYI, most of wp functions have a get_ in front for not echoing, especially the ones used in the loop. The ones that don't have this, will accept a param for not echoing, like `wp_func('limit=10&echo=0')`. You get the point :)

Comment: @user13286 Could you post your solution (with the get_) as an answer so others will know how you solved it?

Comment: I sure will, if @ErkiA or Twisted1919 want to add it as an answer, I would be happy to accept theirs instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution that ended up working for me based on tips from @ErkiA and @Twisted1919:

```
echo '<div class="col-sm-4 retailer" data-state="'.$state.'">
        <div class="locationName">'.get_title().'</div>
        <div class="locationAddress">'.get_field("address").'</div>
      </div>';
```

`get_title()` grabs the title of the Wordpress post and `get_field("address")` retrieves the value from a custom field I've set up using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$title =the_title()
$address = the_field("address");
echo "<div class='col-sm-4 retailer' data-state='$state'>
        <div class='locationName'>$title</div>
        <div class='locationAddress'>$address</div>
      </div>";
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this produces the same result. I ended up changing `the_title` to `get_title` and `the_field` to `get_field` per @eriki-a and all is well now.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: the_title and the_field should return a value. I placed things like that to be simplier, the only problem is, like @Erki A wrote, that the method should return value, not echoing them